# JSDoc create object with some defined and some undefined properties (Typescript [key: string]: any;)

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am trying to convert the following interface to JSDoc

```
export interface Payload {
    [key: string]: any;
    level?: string;
    code?: number;
}
```

so by conversion, it looks like

```js
/**
 * @typedef Payload
 * @type {Object}
 * @property {string} [level]
 * @property {number} [code]
 */
```

But how do I add the option to also add any field there?
How to convert `[key: string]: any;`?

Answer (score 1):

Declare it like the following snippet. It's the same syntax as in Typescript.

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *   [key: string]: any;
 *   level?: string;
 *   code?: number;
 * }} Payload
 */
```